How to solve Render problem in Android Studio
I'm using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2 when i'm using <com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView, it gives render problem.
I've tried everything like Rebuild and Sync project with Files,... but still can't fix the error.
Does anyone know how solve this?
This is how it look
I still haven't found a way to fix T-T
And this is the Problems look

Look at the Problems and / or Error tabs to find out what the "render problem" is.
